# React Native - Animated.Text opacity - animates only 0 => 1, but not 1 => 0

Tags: react-native, animation, opacity

I have an issue with animation of Animated.Text - I want to change opacity depending on presence of error, delivered on props.

Animated.Text is working as expected when opacity is changing from 0 to 1, but it's not executing animation for opposite change(1 => 0) - it just disappears.

```
class FloatingLabelInput extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props)

        this.state = {
            isFocused: false,
            value: '',
        }

        this._animatedIsFocused = new Animated.Value(this.state.value == '' || this.state.value === null ? 0 : 1)
        this._animatedErrorVisibility = new Animated.Value(this.props.error ? 1 : 0)
    }

    componentDidUpdate = () => {

        const { isFocused, value } = this.state
        const { error } = this.props

        Animated.timing(this._animatedIsFocused, {
            toValue: (isFocused || value) ? 1 : 0,
            duration: 200,
        }).start()

        Animated.timing(this._animatedErrorVisibility, {
            toValue: error ? 1 : 0,
            duration: 500,
        }).start()
    }

    createErrorTextStyle = () => {
        return {
            opacity: this._animatedErrorVisibility
        }
    }

render() {

    const { label, error, ...props } = this.props

        return (

            <View style={{ paddingTop: 18, marginTop: 15, marginBottom: 15, width: 230 }}>
                <Animated.Text style={this.createErrorTextStyle()}>{error}</Animated.Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Any suggestions what can I do to make it working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, you should definitely not call `Animated.timing` in `componentDidUpdate`. It will attempt to start your animation way to many time. Move it in a method and call it only when you need to

Comment: Ok, but it didn't help at all. 
Animation is finishing, I get true in the callback...